# Creating an empty 2D array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic, multidimensional-array

I know that arrays are created dynamically, and creating them ahead of time isn't really necessary, but how would one do that with a 2D array? The same way?

```
(for$j)
{
for($i)
    {
    $array[j][i] = "data";
    }
}
```

Something like that? Obviously real for loops, of course.

Comment: an empty 2 dimensional array... `$array = array(array());`

Comment: That way seems correct, if you're sure you want to fill the array with an empty string n*m times.

Comment: I don't know what the deal with the downvotes are. I looked and could not find the answer, so I asked it. Pardon me for trying to learn how to use php.

Comment: upvoted your comment back to 0 :)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

At its absolute simplest, a 2D dimensional array can be created as:

```
<?php
    $emptyArray = array(array());
?>
```

Or as of PHP 5.4 you can also use:

```
<?php
    $emptyArray = [[]];
?>
```

Comment: @Joshua No problem. I think people downvoted because they didn't understand the reasoning behind the question. Not a good reason to downvote. That's what comments are for. Keep on asking questions... :)

Comment: @Joshua time will reveal the truth!

Comment: Careful though, as print_r( $emptyArray ) shows it isn't truly empty (that would be hard as removing the inner [] would render it a 1D array).

Answer (score 24):

You don't create a 2d array in PHP, not in the traditional sense.

The suggestions above about `$a = array(array());` in fact simply creating the following array:

```
$a = array(
    0 => array( )
);
```

Therefore, `$a[0][0] = 'test';` would result in the following:

```
$a = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => 'test'
    )
);
```

At a first glance, it looks like it works, but in fact, this is still not a 2d array.
When you try to use the 2nd row (index 1), at this point, PHP would throw a notice. Eg:

```
$a[1][0] = 'test2';
```

This is because `$a[1]` does not contain anything (remember that `array(array())` simply creating an array at index 0?).

For it to work, you need to yet again do `$a[1] = array();`, or if you want to avoid indices you can do, `$a[] = array();`.

---

**Example**

```
$a = array(); // array of columns
for($c=0; $c<5; $c++){
    $a[$c] = array(); // array of cells for column $c
    for($r=0; $r<3; $r++){
        $a[$c][$r] = rand();
    }
}
```

The above code creates a 5x3 "2d array" of random numbers.

Comment: I wondered where my empty entries came from when using 2-dim arrays. Changed $arr[]=array(); at top of function to $arr[$id]=array(); where it is used and all is fine again

Answer (score 2):

The [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) is always a good way to start for these kind of basic questions.

```
<?php
$arr = array("somearray" => array(6 => 5, 13 => 9, "a" => 42));

echo $arr["somearray"][6];    // 5
echo $arr["somearray"][13];   // 9
echo $arr["somearray"]["a"];  //⁠ 42
?>⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠
```

Comment: I looked at the multidimensional array documentation, there are no examples for creating an empty one.

Answer (score 2):

Could you specify what you are trying to do?
You can loop through multidimensional arrays with the foreach function

```
$ary=array( "subarr" => array("foo","bar") );

foreach($ary as $a){
  foreach($a as $ary_sub){
    echo $ary_sub;
  }
}
```

or

```
foreach($ary["subarr"] as $key=>$subval){
 echo $subval;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I want to create an empty array for handling lines from text files, I just use $array = array();

Answer (score 2):

Using "array(array())" will create a 2D array with an "empty" element in the first position. To create a truly blank 2D array this needs to be removed.

```
<?php
    $emptyArray = array(array());  // Creates a 2D array with one empty element in $emptyArray[0]
    array_pop($emptyArray);        // Pops element[0] off the array
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this.  I thought I was going crazy trying to figure out how I created a blank element at [0]

Answer (score 1):

```
// dynamic 2D array

$twoD = array(array());
$val = 0;

// fill the array
for($r = 0; $r < 4; $r++) {
    for($c = 0; $c < 4; $c++) 
        $twoD[$r][$c] = $val++;
}

// print the current value of $val
echo $val."<br/>------------------<br/>";

// print the array  
for($r = 0; $r < 4; $r++) {
    for($c = 0; $c < 4; $c++) 
        echo $twoD[$r][$c];
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that whenever you use `array(array())` nested function or the short array syntax `[[]]` both will create a 2D array with an `empty` element in the first position. This may bring you some errors so we needs to be removed it.

#### How we can remove an `empty` element?

Well it is  absolute simple as calling the `array_pop()` method to pop the `element[0]` off the array, as this:

```php
<?php
    $a = array(array());
    echo 'Before removing the empty element: \n'
    print_r($a);
    array_pop($a);
    print_r($a);

    $b = [[]];
    echo 'Before removing the empty element: \n'
    print_r($b);
    array_pop($b);
    print_r($b);
?>
```