# how can i create and pass value in multidimensional array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to save some data's in php. I am trying this code

```
$click_free = [];
$ano = 0;
while($res_qry = mysql_fetch_array($sel_qry)){
    $arr_cnt = sizeof($click_free);
    if($arr_cnt != 0){
        $m = 0;
        for($k=0;$k<$arr_cnt;$k++)
        {

            if($click_free[$k][0] == $res_qry['Free_id'])
            {
                $click_free[$k][0] = ($click_free[$k][0]+$res_qry['Qty']);
                $m=1;
            }
        }if($m==0){
            $click_free[$arr_cnt] = [1,];
        }
    }else{
        $click_free[0] = [$res_qry['Free_id'],$res_qry['Qty']];
    }
}
```

But this code has many error. Please help me solve this

Comment: what's your error??

Comment: I think my array declaration was error

Comment: @user7538258 could you please give an example of your input and output array(which you want) ?

Comment: what is the content of $sel_qry ?

Comment: That $sel_qry is date come from data base

Comment: if there is only date come from database then you cannot fetch `Free_id` and `Qty`

Comment: may you show the error or the issue you are encount? or the difference between the output and your expected?

Comment: @Madhan can you give us the sql request  ?

Comment: $sel_qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tmp_free WHERE Bill_No='sm-001/16-17' ORDER BY Free_id,PF ASC,Qty DESC") or die(mysql_error());
 this is my query AND i need a output like [free_id = 1, Qty = 2]

Comment: just after "while($res_qry = mysql_fetch_array($sel_qry)){", put echo "<pre>"; print_r($res_qry); echo "</pre>";die(); and give us the return if you want edit your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating an empty 2D array in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613307/creating-an-empty-2d-array-in-php)

Comment: @Madhan what do you get with my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we got a solution

```
    while($res_qry = mysql_fetch_array($sel_qry)){
    $arr_cnt = sizeof($click_free);
    if($arr_cnt != 0){
        $m = 0;

        foreach ($click_free as $k => $v) {
          if ($v['Free_id']==$res_qry['Free_id']) {
            S_qty=$v['Qty']+$res_qry['Qty'];
            $click_free[$k]['Qty']=$S_qty;
            $m=1;
          }
        }

        if($m==0){
            $click_free[] = array("Free_id" => $res_qry['Free_id'],"Qty"=>$res_qry['Qty']);
        }
    }else{
            $click_free[] = array("Free_id" => $res_qry['Free_id'],"Qty"=>$res_qry['Qty']);
        }
}
```

Thanks to  bfahmi, Kris Roofe, B. Desai , user3542450, dr_debug

Answer (score 1):

```
while($res_qry = mysql_fetch_array($sel_qry)){
     $id_existed = false;

    if(!empty($click_free))
        foreach($click_free as $key=>$ligne)
             if( $ligne[0] == $res_qry['Free_id']){
                  $qty = $ligne[1] + $res_qry['Qty'];
                  $click_free[$key] = [ $ligne[0] ,  $qty ];
                  $id_existed =true;
             }


    if(!$id_existed){
        $click_free[] = [ $res_qry['Free_id'] , $res_qry['Qty'] ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Parse error: parse error in F:\xampp\htdocs\clients\php\erp\pos\chainstore\garments\businesslayer\freeprduct.php on line 68  on line 68 we declare array this same error occurs previously

Comment: @Madhan, you can give us the line 68

Comment: $click_free = array();

Comment: @Madhan : try now

Comment: $click_free = []; sorry the error came for this only i just trying that

Comment: if i use array() means it shows error on $click_free[$key] = [ $ligne[0] , $ligne[1] + $res_qry['Qty'] ];

Comment: let's replace the [] in the array by () - so try again

Comment: $emptyArray = array(array()); i am use this to declare 2D array but it shows same error ( $click_free[$key] = [ $ligne[0] , $ligne[1] + $res_qry['Qty'] ];)

Comment: Parse error: parse error in F:\xampp\htdocs\clients\php\erp\pos\chainstore\garments\businesslayer\freeprduct.php on line 76   AND the line was $click_free[$key] = [ $ligne[0] , $ligne[1] + $res_qry['Qty'] ];

Comment: @Madhan: try this $qty =$ligne[1] + $res_qry['Qty'];  $click_free[$key] = [ $ligne[0] ,  $qty ];

Comment: <?php 

for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++){

 for($j=0;$j<5;$j++){
  $mnk[][] = array($i,$j);
 }

}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($mnk);
echo "</pre>";
?>