# How to work (create and access) empty 2D array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to define in PHP a new 2D array (to fill and access it later in cycle) but I have problem to deal with it. I went through some articles ([e.g. here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613307/creating-an-empty-2d-array-in-php)), but it still does not work for me.

My code is:

```
$part = array(array());
for ($i=0; $i<4; $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j<3; $j++) {
        $part[$i][$j]=3;
    }
}

for ($i=0;  $i<4; $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j<3; $j++) {
        echo "values i=$i, j=$j: $part[$i][$j]\n<br>";
    }
}
```

Result of code above is:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/ftth1/sandbox.php on line 43
values i=0, j=0: Array[0]

Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/ftth1/sandbox.php on line 43
values i=0, j=1: Array[1]

Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/ftth1/sandbox.php on line 43
values i=0, j=2: Array[2]

Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/ftth1/sandbox.php on line 43
values i=1, j=0: Array[0]
...
```

Line 43 mentioned in output is:

```
echo "values i=$i, j=$j: $part[$i][$j]\n<br>";
```

I have tried to use also just a little bit modified version of code from above mentioned article, however result was same:

Code:

```
$a = array(); // array of columns
for($c=0; $c<5; $c++){
    $a[$c] = array(); // array of cells for column $c
    for($r=0; $r<3; $r++){
        $a[$c][$r] = rand();
        echo "$a[$c][$r] \n<br>";
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/ftth1/sandbox.php on line 55
Array[0]

Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/ftth1/sandbox.php on line 55
Array[1]

Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/ftth1/sandbox.php on line 55
Array[2]

Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/ftth1/sandbox.php on line 55
Array[0]
...
```

Line 55 mentioned above is:

```
echo "$a[$c][$r] \n<br>";
```

Could someone help me with this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use braces in you use a "complex" expression in the string interpolation, i.e.

```
    echo "values i=$i, j=$j: {$part[$i][$j]}\n<br>";
```

Note the `{ ... }` around the `$part[$i][$j]` part.

An expression becomes "complex" as soon as it's more than a plain variable name.

See [PHP manual on *simple* string interpolation syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple)
and [*complex* syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex).

Note that the complex syntax can be used for plain variables as well, i.e. you could use `{$i} ... {$j}` for consistency.

Comment: `"values i={$i}, j={$j}: {$part[$i][$j]}\n<br>"` - a must when 'complex', but can be used with any variable. I'd do it this way for readability.

Comment: @ficuscr good point, thank you.

Comment: Thanks. Problem was really in missing brackets. Thanks a lot.